# Unable to use Google Analytics for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, xcode6, cocoapods

I don't know what Happens to the code or google.

I just Downloaded the Sample App for [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/start) for Google.

I downloaded it via pod using:

```
pod try Google
```

and chooses the option for Analytics.

After downloading when I build the project I am getting Linker Error.

> > Fully Stuck Tried All The way available in SO.
> >
> > 1. Removed -ObjC Flag
> > 2. Removed -force-load Flag
> > 3. Changed Load Common Section from Yes to NO

But none of the way help me Out. What is the issue with it.
Here is the Screen shot of the Error:

[image]

Comment: I have tried now.and able to build successfully. make sure you copied configuration plist file to all targets.

Comment: if not working, then after can try by updating pod using `sudo gems install cocoapods` . lmk if anyproblems.

Comment: @preetam I have added the configuration file to all targets..Still I am getting this error

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Following reason of this ERROR :

*Note - Integrated GooGle Analytic without CocoaPods.

1. If latest GA(Google Analytics) sdk is using then better to upgrade to Xcode 7 otherwise it will give you duplicate error (even if configured properly)
2. Running with Xcode 6.2 or < Xcode 7 then better to download September (August) Release Sdk.
3. Go with Xcode and select GA folder and right click - choose show in Finder then all files should be there . If yes then check is there    two different copy exists in other folder .

Thanks

Comment: probably you are right...when I tried to integrate v 3.15 then it was showing error..but when I switch to 3.13 then error was gone...But still I have to install manually without cocoa pods

Comment: Make it correct answer if it solves your problem . I did the same and it working like a bullet .

Answer (score 1):

It basically says that there are functions duplications in the project...

Make sure the following:

- The project does not have #import for .m files by mistake
- In the projects build phases there are no file names duplications
- There are no initialized variables in .h files e.g "int
  variableA = 5"
- If none of the above works, remove in project settings Other Linker
  Flags "-ObjC", that will allow to load the same functions more then
  one time.

Comment: These ways doesn't help..I tried all the way..in the last I have to manually add the framework without cocoa pods.

Comment: @RahulMishra Hi, I can still help you with this. Can you please provide me with the whole error you get in Xcode? In your screenshot I cannot see the top of the error list...